# Why I can't use the filter of MUI GridToolbar?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, material-ui

so I'm trying to filter the date using MUI toolbar grid. This is my actual raw data i get from fetching from the backend.

```
{
        "_id": "6434ffefa330ecceac9e3dbb",
        "email": {
            "_id": "642cee2137f8757b475d1c87",
            "firstName": "test1",
            "lastName": "test1",
            "email": "test1@gmail.com"
        },
        "category": "faculty",
        "affiliation": "ppsc_faculty",
        "createdAt": "2023-12-11T06:36:31.623Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-12-11T06:36:31.623Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6434ec9b42067a96c612b819",
        "email": {
            "_id": "642cee2137f8757b475d1c87",
            "firstName": "test1",
            "lastName": "test1",
            "email": "test1@gmail.com"
        },
        "category": "faculty",
        "affiliation": "ppsc_faculty",
        "createdAt": "2023-12-11T05:14:03.525Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-12-11T05:14:03.525Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

After getting the data, I changed the format of the date when I show it in the UI using this function to make it more readable.

```
{
  field: 'createdAt',
  headerName: 'Date',
  width: 300,
  filterable: true,
  renderCell: (params) => {
    const dateString = params.row.createdAt;
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    const day = date.getDate();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
  },
}
```

So this is what it looks like in the front end.

[image: Sample image]

But when I tried to use the filter method, this is the result. I get an empty array.

[image]

Edit: This is my API call.

```
export const GetRecentSurvey = async (req,res) =>{
    const affiliate = req.query.affiliate

    try {
        let results
        if(affiliate){
             results = await Completed.find({affiliation: affiliate})
                        .populate({path: "email", select: "firstName  lastName email"})
                        .sort({createdAt: 'desc'})

        } else{
             results = await Completed.find()
        }
        res.status(200).json(results)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(error).json(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: When you filter are you making an API call to the backend? If so, what is the MongoDB query that is getting triggered

Comment: @CharchitKapoor No sir , what I did here is get all data, and populate it.

Comment: If you are not making an API call, while filtering are you using some filter function in the UI?

Comment: No sir, what I mean here is I want to use the filter function in `DataGrid`